# Playwright - Getting "locator.click: Target closed" while clicking on an element

Tags: playwright

I have written a simple playwright test to open a url, do some action and then click on the  "next" button and do the same processing again on the page which comes out.

This is to test if the navigation is working properly.

The script seems to be working file except that when I try to click on the element, I get an `locator.click: Target closed`.

I have verified that the element is there and is available for action.

The code is as follows:

```
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle" });
let totalPages = 2;

for (let p = 1; p <= totalPages; p++) {
  let all = await page.$$("div.course-card--container--1QM2W");
  for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    let element = await all[i].asElement().innerHTML();
    let $ = await cheerio.load(element);
    let texts = $(" div .course-card--instructor-list--nH1OC").text();
  }
  page.locator("a.pagination--next--BrXhF").click();
  await page.waitForNavigation();
}
```

Please suggest if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Add await for page.locator("a.pagination--next--BrXhF").click(); replace the second last line with this.

```
await page.locator("a.pagination--next--BrXhF").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't upvote Ketan as I don't have enough reputation points yet, but I believe that to be correct.

You should also avoid using await page.$$ as that is a handle that points to a particular DOM element on a page.  If that element changes, the handle is still pointing at it which can cause unexpected behaviour.  Always to try to use locators instead.

Comment: This answer has useful information.